# Open Website in background using python

Tags: python

I need to open a website in background, and after few seconds of loading, download everything on the page.

I can open the page,

```
import webbrowser
import string
url = 'www.face.com'
webbrowser.open(url)
```

But this opens the webbrowser , while I need not to show the site actually being open. I think I can use wget to download the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to fool the webpage that it is accessed by a human use selenium. But mind that you might download contents using a variety HTTP clients (in which case you won't get any dynamically loaded content).

Python has a built-in HTTP client, but I recoment using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("./phantomjs") # path to phantomjs binary
driver.get("www.face.com")
## refer https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium
driver.quit()  # quit driver
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cgi script and u should import cgi

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) It is a webkit web client written in python (PyQT needed).